# Eclipse can't locate android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

Tags: android, eclipse, flash, webview

I am trying to load a flash in a webview using the codes below

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/");
```

but when I import  android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState; eclipse return an error, asking me to search repositories to find it , the minSDK of my app is 7, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PluginState is available since API level 8. Since you are on 7, you can't use it.
See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.PluginState.html) *(top right corner)*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use minSDK 7, the method should be:

```
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

otherwise, starting from API 8, the method is: setPluginState.